# cron update log filled with "There was an error in previous Update attempt"

Tags: cron, error-log

My var/log/update.log is filled with this:

```
[2017-03-16 14:50:02] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-16 14:51:01] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-16 14:52:01] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-16 14:53:02] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-16 14:54:01] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-16 14:55:01] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
```

If I go back in the log to the point that I see something other than this error message, I see the following:

```
[2017-03-13 18:10:03] setup-cron.INFO: Cleaning generated files... [] []
[2017-03-13 18:10:04] setup-cron.INFO: Complete! [] []
[2017-03-13 18:10:04] setup-cron.INFO: Clearing cache... [] []
[2017-03-13 18:10:04] setup-cron.INFO: Complete! [] []
[2017-03-13 18:10:04] setup-cron.INFO: Job "setup:module:disable {"components":[{"name":"IWD_OrderManager"}]}" has been successfully completed [] []
[2017-03-13 18:10:04] setup-cron.INFO: Job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate config_webservice"]" has started  [] []
Changed cache status:
                        config: 0 -> 1
                        layout: 0 -> 1
                    block_html: 0 -> 1
                   collections: 0 -> 1
                    reflection: 0 -> 1
                        db_ddl: 0 -> 1
                           eav: 0 -> 1
         customer_notification: 0 -> 1
                     full_page: 0 -> 1
            config_integration: 0 -> 1
        config_integration_api: 0 -> 1
                     translate: 0 -> 1
             config_webservice: 0 -> 1
[2017-03-13 18:10:04] setup-cron.ERROR: An error occurred while executing job "setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate config_webservice"]": Could not complete setup:cache:enable ["config layout block_html collections reflection db_ddl eav customer_notification full_page config_integration config_integration_api translate config_webservice"] successfully: Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/miridiatech/shop/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/EntityAbstract.php on line 152 [] []
[2017-03-13 12:11:02] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-13 12:12:01] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
[2017-03-13 12:13:02] update-cron.INFO: There was an error in previous Update attempt. [] []
```

Can anyone please help me track down how to get the updater working again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

delete /var/.update_error.flag

The above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Find this file in `/your/magentodir/var/.update_error.flag` and remove it.

Execute following commands

```
cd <your Magento install dir>
rm var/.update_error.flag
```